# iOS: Store values of UIWebView form in mysql database via PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, ios, xcode

I have created an html form in UIWebView. On tapping submit in the html form I call a php script which inserts the values in mysql database.

I am not able to store the values in the database via POST method in form action. When I tried to debug my script by hardcoding the values I found that the php script is not called.

Please guide me if my approach is wrong - by calling a php script from within an html page embedded in UIWebView

Comment: First you should sure you can access your web server from your simulator or iOS device.

Comment: That should work just fine.. Are you sure your php is working allright?

Comment: Yes, my php works fine when I try to retrieve data from database.

Comment: @iDev you can try your html code in iOS Safari.

Comment: I just checked.. It does not work in safari, but the same code does work (in browser) if I hardcode the values in the PHP script

Comment: @iDev if you use Xcode 4.5 and Safari 6.0 in OS X 10.8.x, you can debug it with it. Just open Safari's menu under "Develope"-> "iPhone Simulator" -> "your app"